# How does one keep informed in a field that relies heavily on scholarly books?

Tags: books

Given that the cycle for writing scholarly books is usually much longer than journal articles, how do professors and students stay informed about their peers' current research? Are there any pathways outside conferences and personal correspondence?

Answer (score 1):

The pace in such disciplines tends to be slower. That is not necessarily bad. Those disciplines tend to prioritize careful thought out arguments over the newest, coolest, most hyped finding. It is not how I and my sub-discipline works, but I recognize that it is a legitimate way of working, that has complementary strengths and weaknesses over a more article or working paper based sub-discipline.

Comment: there is no answer for the question

Comment: I assume you mean that my answer does not answer Kevin's question rather then that Kevin's question has no answer. My answer is implicit: the pathways he mentioned are pretty much the ones used, and a reliance on books will slow the process down in such disciplines, but that is not considered a problem.